# I'd like to be able to programatically setup a site to discourage crawling by search engines

Tags: customization

I'd like to believe this would be in wp_options, but I can't find the right field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `blog_public`:

```
update_option( 'blog_public', '0' );
```